# invalid: This MID is not available on our staging environment - Paytm

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

I am using magento 1.9.4.1 version and trying to install paytm payment gateway through paytm pre-built plugins.

I had follow all steps **using Test API**:

1. Download Plugin through github.
2. Paste app and skin folder into located path
3. Fill all details along with Merchant Id and Merchant Key.
4. Order successfully done.

Now when I am using with **Production API Details** Merchant Id and Key it will showing this error: **invalid: This MID is not available on our staging environment**.

Answer (score 4):

please use this paytm production url "https://securegw.paytm.in/" instead of "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in" testing url

Comment: what if I want to TEST it?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps to rectify & fix this problem:

1. Ensure your MID is correct.
2. Check if the secret key is set up properly on your server.
3. Check whether all the parameters are passed properly while generating checksum and while creating a PaytmOrder.
4. If everything is correct, it's most likely a configuration problem from PayTM's end as it was in my case.
5. Just drop a message to PayTM developer support - https://business.paytm.com/contact-us#developer
6. Please mention all the parameters that you are passing from the backend when you message them:

   - PayTM Test Credentials:

     - Merchant Id
     - Account Secret Key
   - Parameters Sent to Generate Checksum:

     - MID
     - ORDER_ID
     - CUST_ID
     - INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID
     - CHANNEL_ID
     - TXN_AMOUNT
     - WEBSITE
   - generateChecksum Response
   - Parameters used in PaytmOrder:

     - MID
     - ORDER_ID
     - CUST_ID
     - MOBILE_NO
     - EMAIL
     - CHANNEL_ID
     - TXN_AMOUNT
     - WEBSITE
     - INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID
     - CALLBACK_URL
     - CHECKSUMHASH

Comment: I am a bit confused why you are using capital keys everywhere? As per documentation https://business.paytm.com/docs/api/initiate-transaction-api?ref=payments , we need to use small case object keys. Why it is so?

Answer (score 0):

The MID for staging is different that your original merchant MID.
When PAYTM_ENVIRONMENT is set as TEST you must use the MID which was provided for staging not your PROD MID.